# error in c++ Segmentation fault (core dump)when i run the code

Tags: c++

> This the code that resulted the error
> this code is writen in c++
> when i run this code it write segmentation fault(core dump)
> What should i do
> please help me

```
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){

        int size,a,b,c;

        int input[100];

        cin>>size;

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

            cin>>input[i];

        }

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

            for(int j=i+1;i<size;j++){

                if (input[i]>input[j]){

                    c=input[i];

                    input[i]=input[j];

                    input[j]=c;
                }

            }

        }

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

            cout<<input[i];
        }

    }
```

> segmentation error

Comment: Make sure size is less than 100.

Comment: `for(int j=i+1;i<size;j++){` loop has the wrong loop condition. You compare `i` to size not `j` so the loop is an infinite loop causing undefined behavior. I voted to close as a typo.

Comment: Lesson of the day: Learn how to use a debugger. First of all to catch crashes and locate where in your code it happens, and how to examine the values of involved variables. Secondly how to use it to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Answer (score 2):

Change i to j in the second for loop.

```
for(int j=i+1;i<size;j++)
```

to

```
for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
```